# Which event to use to get notified if entity is written to DB (postFlush)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an (Doctrine) entity in a Symfony4 project. What I'm looking for is something like a `postFlush` event (eg *after* it has been written to the DB).

I want to notify other systems that if a Customer is updated, I can dispatch a `CustomerUpdated($customer->id)` message unto my queues. I'm having difficulty finding the proper listener/eventhandler for this. The current problem is that the event is dispatched BEFORE the DB has written, so the consuming service asks info for an entry that doesn't exist yet (for like 2 seconds) or fetches old data as the DB isn't updated yet.

**What I've tried:**

- ```php
  class CustomerListener implements EntityListener {
     public function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
        return [ Events::postFlush ];
     }
     public function postFlush(){ die('looking for me?'); }
  }
  ```

  This does absolutly nothing and fails silently
- I also use the `Events::postUpdate` event, which doesn't work for new entries (the data isn't flushed to the DB yet, resulting in old data).
- I also use the `Events::postPersist` event for new items, which doesnt work because the data doesnt exists in the DB yet! (This is my current challenge).
- [The Doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/events.html#reference-events-post-flush) aren't telling me anything useful either (or im not seeing it).
- Off course I've tried researching this, but I cant seem to find anything.

**What I'm looking for:**

1. Entity gets created OR entity gets updated
2. Entity gets written to database
3. *NOW* DO SOMETHING HERE. I dont want to alter the entity anymore, just notify other systems AFTER save.

Both the postPersist and PostUpdate are between point 1&2, and not suitable. I am aware that flush isn't entity specific, but I need *something*.
It could be I'm using a listener/eventSubscriber incorrect, at this point i;m seeing the forest for the trees.

Comment: The question is not fully clear. What do you mean by "how to get Doctrine postFlush event"? You mean how to implement an event subscriber/listener? Why are you implementing `EntityListener`, and not `EventSubscriber` (which seems what you are trying to do with that code), or even an `EventListener`? You seem to be mixing Doctrine's entity listeners with the symfony event dispatcher.

Comment: Your question is: "how to create an event listener for `postFlush`?", or "how to check for flushed entities on `postFlush`?

Comment: The first one. I've updated my question a bit more. If a company is updated I want to dispatch a CompanyUpdated($company->id), same for a Customer, or Product or Whatever. I want to dispatch that message AFTER it's written in the DB

Comment: If it's the first one, then ditch all the backstory. You are simply asking "how to create an event listener for PostFlush". Which I would be very surprised if it weren't a duplicate. Questions and resources about creating event listeners/subscribers are very abundant. But if you **do** know how to create a subscriber for that event, then show that, and show what's your problem there (e.g. can't get the previously flushed objects). Your latest title is bad because it answers the question directly... "What event can be used after DB write: PostFlush". `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. Makes it confusing.

Comment: If you are asking "is there a PostFlush/lifecycle equivalent event for an entity", then the answer is "no".

Comment: Hm, it's the second one. It seems like a fairly trivial thing to implement and is very useful. We cant be the only ones who want to notify other systems right? How do other people solve this then? No way the whole world implements a sleep(5) everywhere.

Comment: There are multiple ways users deal with this, depending on the context. It's not a trivial task. But the question is rather weak, because is unclear, poorly focused, and frankly does shows little in the way of evidence of research. Haven't voted on it, but if I found it like this with a score of 0, I would have.

Comment: Check how audit bundles do it, for example. E.g. this one: https://github.com/sonata-project/EntityAuditBundle/blob/2.x/src/EventListener/LogRevisionsListener.php

Comment: Hm, I'm trying to clearify it, but as i dont know what I dont know Im having difficulty doing that. And as I dont know what I'm looking for I cant research it very well. I've spent some time on this (I hope that my effort for this topic reflects that) and neither did my colleague. It all looks very similar or simply doesnt work.

Comment: I'll study your example (not right now), see if I can replicate somthing form it. Thanks

Comment: You are starting from a wrong premise ("an entity based postflush event **must** exist"), and digging down from there. You already know what event exists for the operation (from the docs you linked), which ones fire after db write... once you get there, you need to see "from this point, which happens after db write, how can I get the flushed objects". Again, there are similar questions, and simply searching for "pustflush event listener" should find some of those.

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty finding an answer, so I'll answer myself:

There isn't an 'postFlush' event on entity level. There is only a global one, e.g. you get EVERYTHING that is being flushed, all entities for create, update and delete statements.

I've made an EntityFlushListener, which I've stripped to a M.V.P. for an example:

```php
/**
 * This class listens to flush events in order to dispatch they're respective messages unto the queue.
 * There is no specific 'postFlush' event for an entity, so this is a global listener for ALL entities.
 */
class EntityFlushListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    private UnitOfWork $uow;
    private array $storedInserts = [];
    private array $storedUpdates = [];
    private array $storedDeletes = [];

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->uow = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [Events::onFlush, Events::postFlush];
    }

    /*
     * We have to use the 'onFlush' event to get the entities to dispatch AFTER the flush, as 'postFlush' is unaware
     * Please note: duplicates will occur. Logic to fix this might need to be implemented
     */
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        $this->storedInserts = $this->uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions();
        $this->storedUpdates = $this->uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates();
        $this->storedDeletes = $this->uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions();
    }

    /*
     * It has now been written in the DB, do what you want with it
     */
    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        dd(
            $this->storedInserts,
            $this->storedUpdates,
            $this->storedDeletes,
        );
    }
}
```